# SonarCube reports a false possible NullPointerException when using ternary operator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube, ternary-operator

I'm going over the potential NPEs as reported by SonarCube analysis. To my surprise, it does not seem to understand well the ternary operator.
I don't want to re-write the code, since it's used in quite some places - is there a way to make Sonar scanner aware of this ?

```
String input = null;
System.out.println(input == null ? "String is null" : input.length());
```

In the example above Sonar complaints on the call to "input.length" as something that can possibly throw a NPE - but that will never happen, because if input is null, the "String is null" message will be printed, so no attempt to dereference a null object.

Comment: If you think this is a "bug" in sonarqube, you can report an issue at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR